# Predicate com CAST

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, swift

Accessing database `.sqlite` by `sql query` normally, I can use the function `CAST('column' as decimal)`.

By `NSPredicate`, using `CoreData`, how to make this `CAST`? I have one column of type `String` and I need make one `cast` to `decimal` type for compare with other decimal number.

Comment: You can also use intValue. So, do it like this [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ageString.intValue > 21"]

Answer (score 0):

You should not care about how SQLite stores your object graph. In fact, SQLite is pretty liberal about types, so what you should really rely on is the type you specified in your model and your model subclasses.

If your column is a `String` use this:

```
NSPredicate(format: "column = %@", "\(decimal)")
```

You can then process the result further if you need a number rather than a string.

Comment: The problem is that I need to check if it is larger and / or less than the number

Comment: Then either you rely on string comparison, or you fetch all IDs into memory and filter with custom sorting.